# Using a py file as an API endpoint on a hosted server

Tags: mysql, python, web-applications

I need a bit of help and clarity involving how to set up an API service on my web server.

I have written a Python script that is able to do some calculations and string parsing, and I need to make this py file into something that I can query like an API to receive and give JSON responses and etc.

I have looked online and it would seem that using Django is a good way to go, but all of the tutorials I have seen online all work from a local machine, and not a hosted web machine.

I have a domain and servers purchased with iPAge, and I am wondering if anyone would be able to lead me to a tutorial on how to set up a Python API on an external server like one with Ipage? Is there a special program that you all use? Or is there a framework like Django that I need to install to get the ball rolling?

I may be really vague here, but all in all, I am just looking to set up my Python script on my remote web server hosted with iPage to be called via a web browser and to include arguments to be passed to said API.